# How does object move in bottom of swimming pool?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, chaos-theory, turbulence

Suppose there is an object $O$ (swimming goggles) that has fallen to the bottom of a swimming pool. I have the swimming pool circulation pump turned on.

Initially, the object is at some position $P_1$. I stared at it for a few minutes; it's roughly in the same position. However, after ~5 hours, when I looked at it again, it has definitely moved to another position $P_2$. I stared at it again for a few minutes; it's still not moving at all.

Which gets me curious, how exactly does the object move across the bottom of the pool from $P_1$ to $P_2$? Does it move at some really slow constant speed, or completely chaotically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a chaotic system in any real life version. Meaning if you changed the circ pump's starting flow rate by 0.01 L/min, or the goggles' starting position by 1 cm, you might end up with a completely different movement.  Basically impossible to model.
But, on the whole, yes the water's motion caused by the pump is what moves it.